# What happened in the question on sexism in academia?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10588/how-is-sexism-unknowingly-perpetrated-in-academia) is locked, with the message "This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info visit meta."  However, when I click on 'visit meta' (which is a link), it just takes me to the main meta page.  Is there actually any publicly visible 'dispute' going on here?

Comment: Well, now we have a discussion area for this. . . .

Comment: Tara, you might find this question interesting http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13253/why-dont-academic-fields-dominated-by-women-offer-more-scholarships-for-men

Answer (score 14):

A user was attempting to delete and repost answers as "new" to avoid the downvotes associated with it. His justification for this was that the downvotes prevented new users from seeing the answer as readily as the non-downvoted answers.

When informed he could not do so, and instead had to edit the answer in place, he persisted and repeated the process, getting flagged each time. The question has been temporarily locked to prevent "sock-puppetry" from taking place.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  It was just a bit confusing to be directed to meta and then not be able to find anything relevant here.

Comment: That's a blanket statement added by Stack Exchange.

Comment: Maybe ban the user instead of locking the question?

Comment: @DavidKetcheson - That wouldn't prevent the user from coming back on using another IP address to cause more mayhem.  Unfortunately, "protecting" pages is one of the few recourses against uncivil behavior on here.

Comment: Appropriate disciplinary actions were taken, and, as I mentioned, the lock is meant as a temporary "cooling down" period. (I've never seen so many flags issued over a single question.)